# Terminal-only install error for xcode-select on Sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line, terminal, macos-sierra

Attempts to install command line developer tools with `xcode-select --install` just returns the following error: 
`xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tool`
but when the dialog box asks me to confirm my request, it says it failed due to a network problem.  Obviously I am online, I think the problem is that it isn't properly connecting to the right network.

I have seen in similar threads that on 10.12 Sierra that the command line tools can be installed/updated through the Mac App Store, but after my wireless card and some other components were replaced in my MacBook Pro, I can no longer connect to the App Store (or iCloud and the iTunes or iBooks stores) without getting an error saying my device cannot be verified.  I was told by Apple Support to do an erase-and-reinstall to solve the problem, but that didn't work.

This is why I am trying to find a method to install the command line tools directly from Terminal, one which does not require access to the App Store.  xcode-select --install` worked fine on El Capitan and below, so I hope this feature is still available, even if the command is different.

Can anyone help me out, or point me toward an alternate solution?  If not, I guess I'll have to downgrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked on the Apple Developer website and found a Developer Tools download for all the versions of Xcode.  You need an iCloud ID to download, but not a paid developer account.

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/